# Giving grammar without useless symbols / ε-productions

Tags: computational-linguistics, grammar, symbol

I hope some people here are firm with computational linguistics, since I couldn't find any question here about this topic yet.

**Question 1**

As the title says, I'm trying to give an equivalent grammar without useless symbols to this one:

```
G = <{S,A,B,C,D,E,F}, {a,b,c,d,e,f},P,S> with
P = {S -> AB|CD, A -> aE|aA, B -> bB|bC, C -> c|Cc, D -> d, E -> Ee|AF, F -> f}
```

As much as I understood, my solution would look like this:

```
P = {S -> CD, C -> c|Cc, D -> d}
```

**Question 2**

And for deleting the ε-productions in the Grammar

```
G = <{S,A,B}, {a,b,c}, {S -> AB|aAa, A -> ε|bA, B -> c|Ac},S>
```

my solution would look like this:

```
G = <{S,B}, {c}, {S -> B, B -> c},S>
```

But I'm sure this isn't the correct answer, is it?

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics SE! If you want to see other questions about computational linguistics, you can simply click on the tag and it'll give you all the questions that use that tag. :)

Comment: I don't really understand your grammars yet. So the first set of production rules is the one you want to reproduce, right? Then where have all your production rules in the following grammars gone? Clearly the terminal nodes a, b, e and f, all of which can be produced by the first P, are missing in the second P. And where do your empty productions in the third set come from, they don't appear in the first one either? Maybe I just don't get your question, but I don't really have an overview which belongs to what or what exactly you want to end up with...

Comment: The first Grammar (first both code-lines) are completly different from the second Grammar (third code-line). That's why the empty productions aren't in the first Grammar.
The first Grammar should be reduced when Symbols don't lead to terminal nodes or are useless. So the useless symbols would be eliminated. I found this tutorial: http://www.sanfoundry.com/automata-theory-cfg-eliminating-useless-symbols/
Maybe it's clearer with this.
The second one looses the Symbols that lead to empty productions.

Comment: Oh, okay, so it's two different grammars/questions; that wasn't clear. Well, I still don't understand why your second line should be equivalent to the first ones, as there is no way to derive strings inlolving the terminal nodes a, b, e or f, all of which can be produced by the frist line, so the production rules you left out don't seem useless to me. Also, I don't think the second line is correct yet: You wouldn't be able to derive strings containing a or b, which you would be from the first one (i.e. the third code line). Or I'm still missing something, but I still don't see the equivalence.

Comment: There is a construction showing that for any cfg, there is a cfg that is free of empty productions,  generating the same language.  Is that what you mean?  I don't recall how it goes, but it should be referred to in any general text on cfg.  For instance, Ginzberg *The mathematics of context free languages*.  As I recall, it's short but not obvious.  I don't know what you mean by "useless symbol".

Comment: A useless symbol is defined here as a symbol that doesn't lead to a terminal sequence.
My solution for the first grammar would now look like this: `S->CD, C->c|Cc, D->d`
And my second grammar without empty productions would be like this: `S->B|aa|aAab, A->bA|b, B->c`

Comment: I know what you mean by useless productions and empty production rules, but I still don't see how you get to your re-formulations. For the first question: All of your production rules are reachable. The only one that is not-generating is E -> AF. So you could replace that one e.g. by E -> Af and eleminate F -> f, or replace one of the production rules leading to E by production rules including AF on the right-hand side. But that's all I can see so far. For the second question, I don't know yet, would have to try out more...

Comment: ... but as far as I can see, your results don't seem to be correct yet, as the strings that are derivable from S differ between the original gramamr and your modification, for both questions. So I don't really understand how you arrived at your formulations.

Comment: @KendelVentonda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I know now, I got a solution which looks like this:

```
1) P = {S -> CD,C -> c | Cc,D -> d, F -> f}

2) {S -> AB|B|aa|aAa, A -> b|bA, B -> c|Ac}
```